# Failed to get voip phone information from native phone recents by using CallKit

Tags: objective-c, ios10, callkit

I integrated CallKit framework to my app, and make an outgoing call.

I can see the outgoing call in native phone recents.

But when I tab the outgoing call and want to get phone info.
It crashed.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSUserActivity interaction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d4ab90'
```

Here is my code in AppDelegate.m

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0)
{
      INInteraction *interaction = userActivity.interaction;

      INStartAudioCallIntent *startAudioCallIntent = (INStartAudioCallIntent *)interaction.intent;

      INPerson *contact = startAudioCallIntent.contacts[0];

      INPersonHandle *personHandle = contact.personHandle;

      NSString *phoneNumber = personHandle.value;

}`

I crashed in `INInteraction *interaction = userActivity.interaction;`

And I checked with interaction info

```
@property (readonly, nullable, NS_NONATOMIC_IOSONLY) INInteraction *interaction API_AVAILABLE(macosx(10.12), ios(10.0));
```

Following are my environment

`mac: 10.12.1
xcode: 8.1
iOS: 10.1.1`

It doesn't violate the requirement

I search all day but seems no one meet this problem.

Is there anything wrong about code level or have another way to get the phone information?

Comment: Did you mention NSUserActivityTypes in info.plist?

Comment: No, I don't add NSUserActivityTypes key in info.plist. 
Is anykey need to add when using callkit?

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)
NSUserActivityTypes key in info.plist doesn't effect for me.

But I finally find the root cause.
I don't set intents.framework.
I can fixed this with adding intents.framework in Target->Build Phases-> Link Binary with Libraries

Answer (score 3):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Zpw.png)

I have try add NSUserActivity Types bu it not used, I also Use This method sovle This problem.
 I can fixed this with adding intents.framework in Target->Build Phases-> Link Binary with Libraries
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVxLc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you missed out NSUserActivityTypes key in info.plist. Below is the key and value to add, based on the intent you are handling,

[image]